# Mark Gradle build unstable in Jenkins when JUnit tests fail

Tags: junit, jenkins, gradle

I have a Gradle build in Jenkins with various JUnit tests that are executed as part of the build. Now when some of the tests fail the complete build is marked as failed - because Gradle says the build failed.

How can I convince Gradle to succeed the build and then Jenkins to mark the build as unstable? With ant this was no problem at all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [ignoreFailures property in the test task.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:ignoreFailures)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
test {
     ignoreFailures = true
}
```

Comment: Is possible to configure this for jenkins only from commandline? Because with this option FAILED build is logged as SUCCESS

Comment: good build succeed - but jenkins shows build as "success" and not as "unstable" :-/. Anyone has good solution for this? Some plugin for Jenkins? or something

Comment: well - solution is use this. And something from this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148122/how-to-mark-a-build-unstable-in-jenkins-when-running-shell-scripts  I used "Text-finder" plugin

Answer (score 4):

You can use external properties to solve this problem.

```
if (!ext.has('ignoreTestFailures')) {
  ext.ignoreTestFailures = false
}

test {
  ignoreFailures = project.ext.ignoreTestFailures
}
```

In this setup by default failures will fail the build. But if you call Gradle like so: `gradle -PignoreTestFailures=true test` then the test failures will not fail the build. So you can configure Jenkins to ignore test failures, but to fail the build when a developer runs the tests manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can include this in your main build.gradle to be applied to all projects and all test tasks.

```
allprojects{
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        ignoreFailures=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since just ignoring the failed test could not be used in my case i found out the following.
If you are using a scripted jenkinsfile. It is possible to wrap your test stage in a try-catch statement.

```
try {
 stage('test') {
  sh './gradlew test'
 } 
} catch (e) {
  echo "Test FAILED"
}
```

This will catch the build exception thrown by gradle but it marks the build as unstable.