# How can i set the jenkins job to pass when the test are actually failed

Tags: shell, jenkins, build, jobs, status

I'm trying to do something similar to what this guy is doing:
[Jenkins failed build: I Want it to pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505797/jenkins-failed-build-i-want-it-to-pass)

create a pipeline job in Jenkins for all the Known bugs tests, I want the job to PASS when all the tests are FAILED. while when even 1 test is PASS, the job will be GREEN.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148122/how-to-mark-a-build-unstable-in-jenkins-when-running-shell-scripts) this solution

```
         stage('Tests') {
                    steps {
                       script{
                        //running the tests
                       status = sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.knownBug"
                              if (status === "MARK-AS-UNSTABLE") {
                                currentBuild.result = "STABLE"
                                }
                        }
                    }
         }
```

but got an error

```
 Unsupported operation in this context @ line 47, column 39.
if (status === "MARK-AS-UNSTABLE") {
```

------------EDIT---------
Thanks to @yrc I changed the code to

```
try {
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.knownBug"
    } catch (err) {
        echo "Caught: ${err}"
        currentBuild.result = "STABLE"
    }
```

It did help with the error msg, but I want the job to pass when one of the tests is failing. Now, both test and job has failed

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your execution with a try-catch block.

```
try {
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.knownBug"
    } catch (err) {
        echo "Caught: ${err}"
        currentBuild.result = "STABLE"
    }
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't get an error msg now :) but the build is still Failing, while I want it to pass (it fails since the test fails, i want the opposite situation - when the test fails -> the job pass

Comment: @NoyM that shouldn't be the case. Probably the Pipeline is failing from somewhere else. Do you have anything else configured to check the test results?

Comment: nope, it is a very simple 1 test case - only to make sure I'm doing everything right:                     @Category(knownBug.class)
    @Test
    public void test_known_bug() {
        Assert.assertEquals("0", "!");
    }

Comment: And the error i got -  "Error
expected:<[0]> but was:<[!]>"